# HasPyRuCP+: Runtime Error

Tags: обсуждение, 1-апреля

Недавно появился язык *HasPyRuCP+*. Написал программу которая принимает от пользователя граф и две вершины. После чего находит и выводит расстояние между этими вершинами:

```
#include <queue>
import iostream
using *

Graph<int> g;

bfs v u =
  q = queue()
  q << (v, 0)
  map<int, bool> used
  while !q.empty():
    a, d = q.pop()
    used[a] = true
    return d if a == u
    [ n | n <- g.nodes() and 
         g.is_edge(a, n) and 
         !used[n] ].each do |b| {
      q << (b, d + 1)
    }
  float("inf")

cin >> g
v, u = (read . words) input() :: [Int]
puts "Расстояние от вершины %d до #{u} = {}".format(bfs v u) % v
```

Но код не работает! Получаю ошибку:

> Runtime Error

Comment: Прошу прощения, но это не шутка, это вынос мозга в соседнюю галактику.

Comment: Интересно, какие языки тут намешаны? Исходя из вопроса, Хаскель (`bfs v u`), Питон (`while !q.empty():`), C++ (`map<int, bool>`), какие ещё?

Comment: @VladD, Rust, судя по названию языка. CP+ — возможно, C plus plus.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko а по последней строчке я б скорее предположил, что это Ruby, а не Rust.

Comment: @D-side, да, Вы правы, скорее всего, Ruby.

Comment: Хм, а я не вижу, где может крешнутся. Вроде BFS реализован правильно?

Comment: `return d if a == u` - это Perl, или где-то еще такие извращения?

Comment: Ага, похоже на Перл

Comment: @AlexanderZonov в Ruby тоже такое есть. Более того, в стайлгайдах этот вариант предпочитается `if`'у с однострочным телом.

Comment: @VladD, питон же, не? Да и `Py` в названии есть :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: У меня он в списке был :)

Comment: @VladD, я не про список, а про конструкцию `return d if a == u` - вроде питон что-то подобное может?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Правда? Не знал.

Comment: @VladD, вообще-то я не уверен. Но постфиксный if там вроде есть?

Comment: @pank Здравствуйте! Дайте пожалуйста ссылку на документацию этого "нового" языка, а пока не дадите, мой минус за ваш вопрос остается.